# Is it a good practice to pass "this" from html element/control to javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sometimes we need to perform some action in the javascript based on the element, let's say button, from which the action was triggered. In these cases I usually pass **this** but I was always wondering if it's a good practice to do so. Somehow it doesn't look nice when we see a lot of **this** keywords inside the html page. On the other hand, I realize that traversing through the DOM, in case we opt for a selector inside the javascript, is a redundant computation.

Comment: I'd say unobstrusive js is the way to go. I'd prefer to see a lot of querySelectrAll in the js instead of a lot of js inside the html. It makes much more readable

Comment: You should provide code samples so we can offer better advice.

Comment: It's actually best practice to move all of your event handler setup to JS using `addEventListener` (plain JS) or `bind` (jQuery).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's preferable to go with unobtrusive way of writing javascript. Don't include js code inline in your html.

In your case, to bind events use `addEventListener` in this way you can refer to `this` easily.

Example:

```
var buttonElement = document.querySelector("#buttonElementId");
    buttonElement.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
      // inside the function
      // this would refer to the button Element always

      // event would refer to the event object.
      // If you want to find the child elements within the dom
      // use event.target.querySelectorAll("pass your selector here")
    }, false);
```

You need not traverse the DOM again to get the reference. Inside the event handler, `this` will always refer to the target element

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're referring to event handlers? If so, then depending on how they're added, you may not need to pass this.

If they're added in the markup, like so...

```
<button onclick="myHandler(event)">Click me</button>
```

In this case, you can pass an `event` which contains a `target` property that will be your `<button>`.

If they're added via JavaScript, like so...

```
var button = document.getElementById('myButton');
button.onclick = function() { /* ... */ };
```

In this case, `this` will already refer to the button within the scope of your function, so you don't need to pass it. Of course, in *this* example, you can also access the `button` variable too (since it's within your function's scope).